# Why does right encoding to read file change depending on system language in R

Tags: r, encoding, stata

I'm working with a `.dta` file that has some Spanish language strings in a table. I have two machines: one uses English as system language and the other uses Spanish. Depending on which machine I'm using, the correct way to read this file changes:

```
df <- haven::read_stata("data/input/data.dta", encoding = 'latin1') # Works on spanish computer
df <- haven::read_stata("data/input/data.dta") # Works on english computer
```

If I specify no encoding (default is Windows-1252 according to docs) on my Spanish machine, characters like "ñ", "°" are replaced with question marks.

If I specify `latin1` as encoding on my English machine those characters get weird readings, like these:

`ARROZ GRANO LARGO NÂ° 2` instead of `ARROZ GRANO LARGO N° 2` or `LLAVE LAVAMANO BAÃ‘O` instead of `LLAVE LAVAMANO BAÑO`

This goes against what I thought I knew about encodings, so I'm a bit perplexed. I'm sorry I can't provide a reproducible example, but I hope someone has had this kind of issue and understands what's happening and if something can be done not to have to change the reading depending on the machine I'm using.

Comment: Happens to me all the time, as I read content (ill)encoded in multiple encodings.
It depends on the locale of your machine and the encoding of the machine that produced the DTA, which usually but not necessarily encodes in UTF-8. 
The easiest way might be to try `encoding =" UTF-8"` if running in Windows. But if it is possible, try reading the DTA in a *nix machine, perhaps in a virtual machine running Linux, and then save the object as RDS, and then importing back to Windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicolás, I'll try to do what you suggest !